# Get string from list if that string contains substring

Tags: python, string, list, substring

Lets say I have following data:

```
l = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
sub = 'bc'
```

'bc' will allways be a substring for only one element in the list!

and a function that works like this:

```
def f(l, sub):
    return [x for x in l if sub in x][0]
```

So the function will return 'abc' because it has 'bc' in it

My Question is:
What is the other way to write that function so it doesn't use list index? ([0])
Is there a way to do this any 'prettier'?

Comment: If you need only first occurrence, just loop through `l` and return element when you find it. `def f(l, sub): for x in l: if sub in x: return x`

Comment: What about: `next(filter(lambda x: sub in x, l))`

Comment: next((x for x in l if sub in x), None)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `next(..)` with a generator. This will sort of `break` the moment it finds the first instance. Of course, this is assuming one element definitely exists in your list.

```
def f(l, sub):
    return next(x for x in l if sub in x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple:

```
next(x for x in l if sub in x)
```

In this way you don't create the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

```
next(x for x in iter(l) if sub in x)
```